# Is it safe to delete "~/Library/iTunes/Mobile Backups"?

Tags: iphone, backup

Good morning-

Is it possible to delete the contents of `~/Library/iTunes/Mobile Backups`?  This seems to be where backups were stored in older versions of iTunes/iOS?  It appears like it is every backup of iPods, iPhones, etc. I've owned since 2003.

It seems like backups of an iPhone/iPad done locally are now stored in `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync` and that it would be safe to delete the contents of the other folder (`~/Library/iTunes/Mobile Backups`) but would appreciate any confirmation that this is accurate :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. The new location for iOS backups is:

```
~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/
```

This [Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946) was recently updated to reflect this change. Hope this helps.